# create an event in mysql with interval of every 1 day

Tags: mysql, events

I have created an event in mysql for updating a table field. I am trying to update my table value on a daily basis. Is it possible to execute the event when I am switching on (or starting mysql services) my local machine first time of the day? When will the event execute if we are giving  "ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY", if we didnt mentioning any time? I have created this event yesterday mornign at 7.50am, but today till this time event is not executed. Please help... attaching the created event.

```
CREATE EVENT refund_flag
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
DO
UPDATE dlbcc_purchase set flg_refund = 'Y' where txn_type = 'Purchase' and flg_refund = 'N' and due_date < sysdate();
```

Comment: Do you have the MySQL event scheduler turned on?

Comment: Yes....I have turned it on. And also the event executed once at the time of creating the event (yesterday morning 7.50 am)